# Bitmap Caret not working WinApi

Tags: c++, winapi

**EDIT:**
Now this is totally strange, seems like the ::CreateCaret is somehow interpreting the colors of the bitmap wrong, when I use RGB ( 255,255,255 ) the resultant caret is of black color, and when I use RGB ( 53,53,52 ) the resultant caret if of RGB ( 253,253, 252 ) and if I use RGB ( 0,0,0 ) for the bitmap then the caret doesn't show up atall.

---

I am trying to create a custom caret, based on a bitmap, for an application.
The ::CreateCaret creates the caret of the correct size, that is, the size of the bitmap, but it doesn't shows the bitmap, instead I get a black caret of the bitmap size. I have checked with ResourceHacker, the bitmap is getting loaded in the exe.
What could be wrong ? I am following this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Hiding_a_Caret) on microsoft website.

I am working in windows 7.

Here is a screeshot :

[image]

here is my code :

resource.rc

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"


IDB_CARET  BITMAP  DISCARDABLE  "caret.bmp"
```

resource.h

```
#define  IDB_CARET  201
```

main.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"


HINSTANCE hInstance;
HBITMAP caret;

/*  Declare Windows procedure  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

/*  Make the class name into a global variable  */
char szClassName[ ] = "WindowsApp";

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR lpszArgument,
                    int nFunsterStil)

{
    HWND hwnd;               /* This is the handle for our window */
    MSG messages;            /* Here messages to the application are saved */
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */



    hInstance = hThisInstance;



    /* The Window structure */
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

    /* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
    /* Use Windows's default color as the background of the window */
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;

    /* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
        return 0;

    /* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
           0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
           szClassName,         /* Classname */
           "Windows App",       /* Title Text */
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, /* default window */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
           544,                 /* The programs width */
           375,                 /* and height in pixels */
           HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
           NULL,                /* No menu */
           hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
           NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
           );

    /* Make the window visible on the screen */
    ShowWindow (hwnd, nFunsterStil);

    /* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    /* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
    return messages.wParam;
}


/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:

            ::DestroyCaret (  );

            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */

            break;
       case WM_CREATE:
             {
                 caret = ::LoadBitmap (  hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE ( IDB_CARET )  );
                 if ( caret == NULL )   ::MessageBox ( 0, "LoadBitmap", "LoadBitmap", 0 );   
             }
             break;
        case WM_SETFOCUS:
             {
                 if ( ::CreateCaret (   hwnd, caret, 0, 0   ) == 0 ) ::MessageBox ( 0, "CreateCaret", "CreateCaret", 0 );

                 if ( ::SetCaretPos ( 100, 100 ) == 0 ) ::MessageBox ( 0, "SetCaretPos", "SetCaretPos", 0 );

                 if ( ::ShowCaret ( hwnd ) == 0 ) ::MessageBox ( 0, "ShowCaret", "ShowCaret", 0 );
             }
             break;
        case WM_KILLFOCUS:
             {
                 if ( ::DestroyCaret (  ) == 0 ) ::MessageBox ( 0, "DestroyCaret", "DestroyCaret", 0 );
             }
             break;
       default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check return values of all API calls.

Comment: @AlexFarber I did, everything is working

Comment: Nope, you did not check any return values.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How did you come to that conclusion ? Here is how checked the return values (original post updated).

Comment: I came to that conclusion for the simple reason that your original code did not check any return values. I guess you could usefully provide a screenshot and the .bmp file that is linked as a resource

Comment: Works just fine here. What is your bitmap?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that's strange, I had a 10x20 px solid white rectangle bitmap, but when I changed the color to RGB 0,173,239 then the resultant caret was of RGB 200,101,39

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, the problem is how the windows handle the caret color.

Basically, if the bitmap color is same as the background color of the client area of the concerned window then the resultant caret is of Black color, and if the bitmap color is inverse of the background color of the client area of the concerned window then the resultant caret is of White color. We can use the invert option of Photoshop to create a White Caret or can create the bitmap in memory.

The creation of caret with other then Black or White colors is more complicated, but the idea is same.

Ofcource if the background of the concerned window or the caret is not of a solid color then it become even more complicated.

---

Taken from : [Microsoft website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/84054)

*To create a caret, first create a bitmap with the desired pattern. To display the caret, Windows exclusive-ORs (XORs) and takes the opposite of the result (the NOT of the result) of the bitmap with the background of the client window. Therefore, to create a white caret, create a bitmap that when XOR'd with the window background will have an opposite value that will create a white color. It is when the caret blinks that Windows uses the reverse of the bitmap XOR'd with the background to draw the caret; this creates the white blink seen on the screen.*

Answer (score -2):

In CreateCaret (   hwnd, caret, 0, 0   ), you are specifying 0 width and 0 size, specify a non-zero size there. Also, make sure that the caret position is set within your window area, then only you would be able to see it.
check this: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648398(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) 
for bitmap, use similar to the code below:

```
// Load the application-defined caret resource. 
    caret = LoadBitmap(hinst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(120));

// Create a bitmap caret. 

    CreateCaret(hwnd, caret, 0, 0);
```

Comment: The documentation states very clearly that these parameters are ignored if a bitmap is passed

Comment: And I am able to see the caret, but it's all black and not showing the bitmap, as it should be.

Comment: @DebasishJana The code in the question does indeed call `LoadBitmap`.