I cannot create a caret using a bitmap
Even though I changed the WM_SETFOCUS section of the code under the "Processing Keyboard Input" heading in the link below to use a bitmap for caret, I cannot get any caret image on the screen and no error message from CreateCaret() function. I have checked that the code created a bitmap or not.
https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/windows/win32/menurc/using-carets
        case WM_SETFOCUS:
        {
             int caret_width = (nCharX/5)>=2 ? nCharX/5 : 2;
             RECT rcCaret = { 0, 0, caret_width, nCharY };
             hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
             HBITMAP hBitmapNew = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, caret_width, nCharY);
             HDC hdcMemNew = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
             SelectObject(hdcMemNew, hBitmapNew);
             HBRUSH caretBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,0,0));
             FillRect(hdcMemNew, &rcCaret, caretBrush);

             if(CreateCaret(hwnd, (HBITMAP) hBitmapNew, 0, 0)==0) {
                MessageBox(NULL, "CreateCaret() error!", "Error", MB_OK) ;
             }

             // CreateCaret(hwnd, 0, nCharX, nCharY); // Adjust the caret position.
             SetCaretPos(nCaretPosX * nCharX, nCaretPosY * nCharY); // Display the caret.
             ShowCaret(hwnd);

             DeleteObject(caretBrush);
             DeleteObject(hdcMemNew);
             DeleteObject(hBitmapNew);
             ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
        }
        break;

I tried to change caret bitmap, but no caret image on the window.
Bitmap variable should not be deleted. The latest version of the code is below. Thanks to everybody.
HBITMAP hBitmap; // Global variable

case WM_SETFOCUS:
{
     int caret_width = (nCharX/5)>=2 ? nCharX/5 : 2;
     RECT rcCaret = { 0, 0, caret_width, nCharY };
     hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
     HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
     hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, caret_width, nCharY);
     HBITMAP hBitmapOld = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
     // To get a red colored caret, we can use the result of XOR operation
     // between the background color and the red color as the bitmap color.
     HBRUSH caretBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(236, 236, 236) ^ RGB(255, 0, 0));
     FillRect(hdcMem, &rcCaret, caretBrush);

     if(CreateCaret(hwnd, (HBITMAP) hBitmap, 0, 0)==0) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "CreateCaret() error!", "Error", MB_OK) ;
     }

     SetCaretPos(nCaretPosX * nCharX, nCaretPosY * nCharY);
     ShowCaret(hwnd);

     DeleteObject(caretBrush);
     DeleteObject(hdcMem);
     SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmapOld);
     ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
}


Not related to the problem, but you need to unselect hBitmapNew from hdcMemNew and reselect the previous bitmap before you delete them: HBITMAP hBitmapOld = SelectObject(hdcMemNew, hBitmapNew); ... SelectObject(hdcMemNew, hBitmapOld);

Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906842/ as it talks about how the colors of the bitmap affect how it is displayed on the window. Maybe the caret is actually being created and you just cant see it?

Dear Remy,
Thanks for your kind reply.
The main window background color is: RGB(236,236,236)
Then, I have changed the bitmap color to RGB(19, 236, 236):
HBRUSH caretBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(19, 236, 236));

I have applied XOR operation to the window background color and the bitmap value, to obtain a red color. Unfortunately, I did not get the result I expected.
0x00ECECEC ^ 0x00ECEC13 = 0x000000FF;


According to the Doc:CreateCompatibleBitmap function
When a memory device context is created, it initially has a 1-by-1 monochrome bitmap selected into it. If this memory device context is used in CreateCompatibleBitmap, the bitmap that is created is a monochrome bitmap. To create a color bitmap, use the HDC that was used to create the memory device context.
I suggest you could try to use the HDC that was used to create the memory device context in the CreateCompatibleBitmap function.

Dear Jeaninez, thanks for your suggestion. I checked again. I have used the HDC that was used to create the memory device context in the CreateCompatibleBitmap function.

Whether the window could receive the keyboard focus?

When I use CreateCaret(hwnd, 0, nCharX, nCharY); instead of bitmap, black caret is blinking in the window.

I tried to use CreateCompatibleBitmap to create a bitmap caret, and also couldn't show the bitmap caret.
I suggest you could try to use LoadBitmap function to create a bitmap caret.

Before CreateCompatibleBitmap, I have tried LoadBitmap function to load the specified bitmap resource from a module's executable file. Then, I have tried LoadImage function both to load bitmap from resource and to load from file with LR_LOADFROMFILE as last parameter (fuLoad) of the function. Unfortunately, none of the methods gave the expected result.

What is the result you expect? Why the bitmap caret created via LoadBitmap function couldn't meet your requirements?

Using LoadBitmap requires a separate bitmap for each caret color. CreateCompatibleBitmap can easily create a different caret color depending on user's color choice.
